# Are multithreaded database transactions via connection-pooling threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, thread-safety, connection-pooling

**Example Scenario:**

Using a threadpool in java where each thread gets a new connection from the connectionpool and then all threads proceed to do some db transaction in parallel. For example inserting 100 values into the same table.

Will this somehow mess with the table/database or is it entirely safe without any kind of synchronization required between the threads?

---

I find it hard to find reliable information about this subject. From what I gather DB engines handle this on their own/if at all (PostgresQL apparently since version 9.X). Are there any well written articles explaining this further?

Bonus question: Is there even a point to make use of parallel transactions when the DB runs on a single hdd?

Comment: If you're sure that each thread is using a separate connection (pooling, as you say), then it's literally like multiple different users/computers connect to the database. So problems can only happen at database level. Things you'll have to deal with in this case include unique constraints (OK if you've made sure that threads don't interfere with each other's data), deadlocks (if those different transactions lock overlapping sets of rows), etc. But just the fact that you're connecting in parallel to the database and performing multiple transactions shouldn't cause a problem in itself.

Comment: "each thread is using a separate connection". Isn't this the only way to do it anyway? I thought issues arise once you start sharing a single connection between multiple threads. Hence why people use connectionpools which provide you multiple

Comment: `"Isn't this the only way to do it anyway?"` Yes, that's the way to do it **right**. We're saying the same thing here. I just wanted to note that there are ways to do it wrong.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was thrown off by "So problems **can** only happen at database level." as that's basically my question. Can/will problems happen and how to prevent them

Comment: The only problems I can think of are only if threads walk on each other's toes. You could run into a deadlock (e.g. if threads lock the same rows, etc.)

Comment: I know you mean it well :) but again, this is exactly what I am asking. Will for example a deadlock occur when 2 threads insert into the same table? You don't quite seem to know yourself haha. Which is why I also asked for some articles/papers on this topic, as basically all questions related to this topic are answered by some random dudes who do not reference anything. A lot of half-truths floating round

Comment: If two connections/threads insert into/update the same table, that won't lead to a deadlock unless they work on the same rows. So if thread 1 locks primary key A and thread 3 locks primary key A too, and that happens at the same time, then one will lock another or a deadlock can even occur if the reverse happens at the same time. This is why I said: if you're sure that those threads are working on non-overlapping row sets, then you should in general be okay... Try reading about [transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) and their isolation levels, etc

Comment: @ernest_k It won't lead to a deadlock unless they claim multiple locks in different orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the database itself is conforming to [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) you are fine (although every now and then someone finds a bug in some really strange situation).

To the bonus question: for PostgreSQL it totally does make sense as long as you have some time for collecting concurrent transactions (increase value for [commit_delay](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-COMMIT-DELAY)), which then can help combining disk I/O's into batches. There are also other parameters for transaction throughput tuning, most of which can be pretty dangerous if **D**urability is one of your major concerns.

Also, please keep in mind that the database client also needs to do some work between database calls which, when executed sequentially, will just add idle time for the database. So even here, parallelism helps (as long as you have actual resources for it (CPU, ...).